# Pass a Parameter from Power Query to T-SQL and Still Edit Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to use a Power Query parameter inside of a T-SQL query, but still allow for me to edit the source query in the "Edit Settings" portion like in linked image? I know that you can insert the parameter in via the Advanced Editor screen, but then it becomes difficult to make additional edits to the query.

Essentially, I'd still like to have the parameter used in the SQL query, but without losing the ability to easily make edits. I'm using Power Query in Power BI (Desktop). Thanks for your help.

[image: Screenshot example of what I'd like to do]

Comment: What's the exact problem? If you want to further edit the query, probably the PowerQuery editor is not the best one to write SQL, so just copy-paste it somewhere else, edit it and put it back in the Power Query editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

When you create that query, the first Applied Step (see the right-hand pane in your screenshot) will be M code that looks like this:

```
= Sql.Database("server", "db", [Query="SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE Date = [Parameter]"])
```

If you have a parameter `Param`, you can edit the code to be dynamic like this:

```
= Sql.Database("server", "db", [Query="SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE Date = "&Text.From(Param)])
```

---

However, PowerQuery can do its own query folding that might make this easier and more efficient in many cases.

If you load that table in without using a SQL statement, your query should something look like this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server", "db"),
    dbo_ABC = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="ABC"]}[Data]
in
    dbo_ABC
```

From there you can apply a filter on your `Date` column (pick any date from the dropdown), which should yield another step that looks something like this:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_ABC, each ([Date] = #date(2019, 12, 31)))
```

Here, you can replace whatever date you picked with your date parameter so that now your whole query looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server", "db"),
    dbo_ABC = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="ABC"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_ABC, each ([Date] = Param))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

(Make sure that the `Date` column and the parameter are the same data type or you'll get an error.)

Now right-click on that last step in the Applied Steps like and choose 'View Native Query' and you'll see the generated SQL code that PowerQuery is actually sending back to the server. It'll look something like this (where the parameter is written explicitly).

```
select [_].[Col1],
    [_].[Col2],
    [_].[Col3],
    [...]
from [dbo].[ABC] as [_]
where [_].[Date] = '2019-12-31' and [_].[Date] is not null
```

Anyway, the point is that you can work in the query editor instead of modifying your query string.